# Are there any environment-based settings written for 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, campaign-settings, environmental-hazards

I was a big fan of the 3e "environment" books such as Stormwrack, Sandstorm, and Frostburn—adventure settings in which the extreme environments presented major obstacles or threats to life, and dealing with survival in those environments was a significant focus.

There was a lot to like about them, e.g. Sandstorm: ~10 pages showing the effects of extreme temperatures, things like:

> At 141-180 degrees F, PCs must make Fort. (DC 15, +1 per previous)
> check every 10 minutes or take 1d4 points of non-lethal damage

and adjudicating the effects of dehydration; descriptions of different kinds of desert environs (Badlands, Salt Flats, Petrified Forests, &tc.); table describing the effects of sandstorms and whirlwinds etc; "flavor" components for how the extreme conditions of various deserts might affect different races; etc.

They generated many exciting hours of adventures. What setting/adventure content exists for D&D 4e that fits into this environmental challenge category? Have any of these 3e books been updated into the 4e rules, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the Dark Sun rules for travel, and they could indeed be adapted to other environments.  The basic framework of sun sickness looks to be very flexible.

Comment: It seems like this is the best answer I'm likely to get...thanks for the concrete answer on Dark Sun. I hope someone gets around to doing Frostburn and Stormwrack as well - I think these three books might easily be the best role playing value I ever got out of a WotC resource.

Answer (score 0):

Dark Sun contains extended rules for desert travel and the related effects. I haven't seen these yet but they could might be adapted to fit in other environments.